# Type of a model and params in Prisma

Tags: typescript, prisma

Let's say I have this function:

```js
const updateModel = async(model, params) => {
    await model.update(params)
}
```

Here, the model is any model in Prisma, and the params is an object consisting of `where` and `data` objects for updating the model. What would I put the type of model and params to make it typesafe in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this -

```ts
import { PrismaClient } from "prisma";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const updateModel = async(model: typeof prisma.[~name of your model~], params: Parameters<typeof prisma.[~name of your model~].where>) => {
    await model.update(params)
}
```